# Book 010, Number 3901

Tags: quran, source-identification

> "Jabir (Allah be pleased with him) reported: There came a slave and pledg- ed allegiance to Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon him) on migration; he (the Holy Prophet) did not know that he was a slave. Then there came his master and demanded him back, whereupon Allah's Apostle (may peace be upon him) said: Sell him to me. And he bought him for two black slaves, and he did not afterwards take allegiance from anyone until he had asked him whether he was a slave (or a free man)" - Book 010, Number 3901

I found the above verse/hadith somewhere and whenever I search to find its source, the top pages (except perhaps the first) are from Islamophobic websites that I don't trust, but I can't find it in Quran.com hence I want to know the validity of it.

Which chapter in the Quran is it from? If it's not from the Quran, where is it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quote isn't a verse of the Quran so searching it on Quran.com is a waste of time. It is a hadith which you may find in [sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/22/152) in The Book of Musaqah, Chapter: "The permissibility of selling animals for animals of the same kind and of different quality".

The hadith is also quoted in other hadith collections like sunan [an-Nasa'i](http://sunnah.com/nasai/44/173), sunan [ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1329800) and Jami' [at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/14/39).

Feel free to ask about the hadith explanation and it would be nice if you could also quote the related "explanations" of your actual source!

Answer (score 1):

in the name of allah the most beneficent the most merciful

the hadith you mentioned in arabic is :

> حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ يَحْيَى التَّمِيمِيُّ، وَابْنُ، رُمْحٍ قَالاَ
>   أَخْبَرَنَا اللَّيْثُ، ح وَحَدَّثَنِيهِ قُتَيْبَةُ، بْنُ سَعِيدٍ
>   حَدَّثَنَا لَيْثٌ، عَنْ أَبِي الزُّبَيْرِ، عَنْ جَابِرٍ، قَالَ جَاءَ
>   عَبْدٌ فَبَايَعَ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم عَلَى الْهِجْرَةِ
>   وَلَمْ يَشْعُرْ أَنَّهُ عَبْدٌ فَجَاءَ سَيِّدُهُ يُرِيدُهُ فَقَالَ
>   لَهُ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ بِعْنِيهِ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فَاشْتَرَاهُ
>   بِعَبْدَيْنِ أَسْوَدَيْنِ ثُمَّ لَمْ يُبَايِعْ أَحَدًا بَعْدُ حَتَّى
>   يَسْأَلَهُ ‏"‏ أَعَبْدٌ هُوَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>      [sahih muslim 22/152](http://sunnah.com/muslim/22/152)

this hadith is Athentic , you mentioned something about that Islamophobic websites use it . actually i don't find anything in this hadith could be used against islam . if there is anything feel free to ask about

Comment: @NewbieLearner so what exactly is the problem the trade 1 for 2 or slavery? Maybe you should post it as a new Question!